# impossible combination of address sizes and invalid effective address on simple operation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I have some assembly, the following lines of which are causing `nasm` to complain about `impossible combination of address sizes` and `invalid effective address`:

```
mov [rbp], eax
mov [rbp - 4], eax
mov edi, [rbp]
mov esi, [rbp - 4]
mov edi, [rbp - 8]
mov [rbp - 8], eax
```

Why is this?

Comment: Likely because of the way you are assembling the file. Since this code is 64-bit use `-f elf64` if you are on Linux `-f macho64` on OS/X. Otherwise in your file you will have to places the `bits 64` directive before the code

Answer (score 1):

Stupid mistake, pointed out by Michal Petch.

Forgot to add the `-f macho64` flag (`-f elf64` on Linux).